# How to make a list of pairs unique in Jinja?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a dictionary with array values coming from an Ansible vars file.

```
ipfilter:
  zone1:
    - { application: "app 1", local_ip: 1.1.1.1 }
    - { application: "app 1", local_ip: 1.1.1.1 }
    - { application: "app 2", local_ip: 2.2.2.2 }
  zone2:
    - { application: "app 3", local_ip: 3.3.3.3 }
    - { application: "app 4", local_ip: 4.4.4.4 }
    - { application: "app 4", local_ip: 4.4.4.4 }
```

The problem is, that the tuple of `application` and `local_ip` is not unique, because the objects contain additional data, which I have omitted in the example, because it is not relevant for the following script.

The script is a Jinja template delivered by Ansible to a Solaris server:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -eu
cat <<';' |
{% for zone, rules in ipfilter.items() %}
{%   for rule in rules %}
 {{zone}} {{rule.application}} {{rule.local_ip}}
{%   endfor %}
{% endfor %}
;
sort | uniq | while read zone application local_ip; do
  ipfcfg delete "$zone" "$application" "$local_ip"
done
```

The outer loop iterates over the dictionary and the inner loop iterates over the array values.

I am not able to make the list of tuples unique with Jinja. Therefor I had to use the `sort | uniq | while read` loop in Bash. This is far from perfect and has its own limitations.

How to make the list of tuples unique in Jinja instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get unique list pairs from *your example*, you can simply use:

```
ipfilter.values() | sum(start=[]) | unique
```

But this will not work in your case, because you have omitted other keys from your original data, so `unique` filter will not work.

You will have to workaround this with a bit of Ansible variables templating magic prior to your task:

```
# construct list of tuples
- set_fact:
    tmp_app: '{"app":"{{item.application}}","ip":"{{item.local_ip}}"}'
  with_items: "{{ ipfilter.values() | sum(start=[]) }}"
  register: tmp_apps
# pass uniq list to template
- template:
    src: script.j2
    dest: script.sh
  vars:
    uniq_apps: "{{ tmp_apps.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.tmp_app') | list | unique }}"
```

and script.j2:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -eu
{% for app in uniq_apps %}
ipfcfg delete "{{app.app}}" "{{app.ip}}"
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works but I still do not understand what `sum(start=[])` does. Why do I have to use `sum` although I do not want to summarize anything?

Comment: With `ipfilter.values()` you get list of lists (because your zones are lists). But you need only inner lists, so we `sum` them to make a long plain list that contains all inner lists.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Konstantin Suvorov's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40618657/402322) and [Sean Vieira's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27733533/402322) answer to another question I was able to do all of my stuff in Jinja.

```
#! /bin/bash
set -eu
{% set all_rules = [] %}
{% for zone, rules in ipfilter.items() %}
{%   for rule in rules %}
{%     set x = all_rules.extend([{'zone': zone, 'application': rule.application, 'local_ip': rule.local_ip}]) %}
{%   endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% for item in all_rules|unique %}
ipfcfg delete {{item.zone|quote}} {{item.application|quote}} {{item.local_ip|quote}}
{% endfor %}
```